# What kind of sorcery is this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have one button add 1 and another button add 2 using the code below. It's going all kinds of wrong.. You can only use the button +2 once (then you have to use the +1 button, otherwise pressing the +2 again doesn't do anything) And using the +1 button adds 1 to the number you had before you added 2 (by using the +2 button).. Also; if you give a number as input and you use the +1 button the first time it gives you the exact number you gave as input... The +2 button does not do this..

What should i change and what is happening?

```
<title>testingstuff</title>
<script type = "text/javascript">


var givenNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Give a number to start with"))
var givenNumber2 = givenNumber


function addingFunc() 
{
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = givenNumber2 ++ ;
};

function addingFunc2()
{
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = givenNumber2 + 2;
};
```

```
<button id="add_number" onclick="addingFunc()">Add 1 to number</button>
<br />
<button id="add_number" onclick="addingFunc2()">Add 2 to number</button>
<br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Use `givenNumber2 += 2;` to change the actual value of `givenNumber2`

Comment: Also, postfix `++` returns the value unaltered and then changes the value.

Comment: ... and you might also want to change the +1 code to something similar: `givenNumber2 += 1;`

Comment: Allright, that fixes one thing. But it still looks like the +1 function is one behind (if i give 3 as input and press the +1 button it gives me 3 instead of 4)

Comment: Bad programming != Sorcery

Comment: Wow, it works when i use += 1 and += 2. Thats great.. xP

Comment: And yea Shomz i know it was just bad programming. But trust me learning to program does feel like trying to understand sorcery sometimes.

Comment: @user3151753 Sure, but here's an advice: don't ever use such question titles. It makes you look bad. :) Just simply explain what the problem is.

Comment: Excellent advice from @freakish

Comment: Well it did get some attention which got me to my answer =] But sure i'll take your advice.

Comment: @user3151753: JavaScript questions (fairly basic, language-level ones anyway) usually get answered very quickly. Nothing wrong with being a little light, but better to make your overall title and question descriptive of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanics behind it is quite easy actually. You replace the content of `div` with `givenNumber2 + 2`. You **don't modify `givenNumber2` in addingFunc2**. Try this:

```
function addingFunc2()
{
    givenNumber2 += 2;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = givenNumber2;
};
```

It's far from sorcery...

The reason why `addingFunc1` is behind is because of operator precedense. `givenNumber2++` updates the number **after** setting `innerHTML`. Use either `++givenNumber2` or simply follow the same rule as above.

Comment: The +1 code *does* modify it, and it should also be changed so that it's a pre-increment instead of a post-increment.

Comment: @Pointy Yep, yep, I've meant `addingFunc2` only.